# In Java, how do I create a bitmap to solve "knapsack quandary"

Tags: java, bitmap, knapsack-problem

I'm in my first programming course and I'm quite stuck right now. Basically, what we are doing is we take 16 values from a text file (on the first line of code) and there is a single value on the second line of code. We read those 16 values into an array, and we set that 2nd line value as our target. I had no problem with that part.

But, where I'm having trouble is creating a bitmap to test every possible subset of the 16 values, that equal the target number.

IE, say we had these numbers:

```
12   15   20   4   3   10   17   12   24   21   19   33   27   11   25   32
```

We then correspond each value to a bitmap

```
 0    1    1   0   0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    0
```

Then we only accept the values predicated with "1"

```
     15   20                     12   24   21        33             25
```

Then we test that subset to see if it equals the "target" number.

We are only allowed to use one array in the problem, and we aren't allowed to use the math class (haven't gotten to it yet).

I understand the concept, and I know that I need to implement shifting operators and the logical `&` sign, but I'm truly at a loss. I'm very frustrated, and I just was wondering if anybody could give me any tips.

Comment: so the task here is to compare the 2nd line (in binary) to each of the numbers given in the first line? Is your problem about converting integers to binary? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you need...

Comment: when you say "test that subset to see if it equals the 'target' number" what exactly do you mean?  Are you supposed see if the arithmetic sum of those numbers equals the target?

Comment: Haha, I'm having trouble understanding it myself. Apparently there's something called a "bitmap" in java, that allows an association between a bit (1/0) and an element in the set. For every element in the set we assign one bit to correspond to one element of the set. 

We then take the values that are "true" (1's) and see if they match the "target" value of the text file.

Basically:
1. Generate all possible subsets for the 16 elements
2. Walk across each subset and see which subsets = target

Comment: @Matthew, how are you defining equality between a set of numbers and a single value?

Comment: Hint: Most people reading this wont know what you mean by "Knapsack quandry". In fact, Google doesn't appear to know this term either.

Comment: Let me try and say it simpler:

We have 16 numbers

We generate all possible subsets of the 16 numbers.

We then see what subsets (when the numbers within that subset are added up) equal the target number.

But the "bitmap" is what is throwing me off. I'm confused as to how to implement it into a solution.

Comment: The knapsack problem, ie, using brute force to generate all possible subsets of N set of numbers. Quandary is just a fancy word for problem.

Comment: The knapsack problem, as defined by wikipedia, is something quite different. Anyway, let's focus on your question. Do you need to find all such subsets, one such subset, or simply whether such a subset exists?

Comment: @MikeDeck First, thanks so much for the help, secondly I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. There are 16 numbers in an array, somehow I'm supposed to take those numbers, generate all the possible subsets of those numbers (2^n), then by using something called "bitmap", map (1/0 or T/F) values onto each number. Like, if number 12 isn't present in a specific subset, it is 0, but if it is, it is 1. I'm really not sure what this is, or how to use it, I was simply told it exists. That's where I'm at, I'm very confused.

Comment: @meriton I need to find all such subsets that when added up, equal a defined "target" number. So, just for example, if my target number is 10, I'd need a subset that adds up to 10. Duplicate sets are allowed, and none of the 16 numbers will ever contain a number higher than the target number (for simplicity sake).

Comment: @Matthew It's probably a BitSet and not a bitmap (at least that's a useful class from java for your problem). Look into it :). Alternatively you can have a simple counter from 1 to 2^16 and for each step you get the counter value convert into binary and for each set bit you use the number from the original array to see if you can sum to the target number.

Answer (score 0):

To generate all possible bit patterns inside an int and thus all possible subsets defined by that bit map would simply require you to start your int at 1 and keep incrementing it to the highest possible value an unsigned short int can hold (all 1s). At the end of each inner loop, compare the sum to the target. If it matches, you got a solution subset - print it out. If not, try the next subset.
Can someone help to explain how to go about doing this? I understand the concept but lack the knowledge of how to implement it.

Comment: Yeah this is the relative idea. I just don't understand "how" this is done.

Comment: Well, I've asked him and the TA a couple times, I just really don't understand the explanations that were given. I'm at my last resort, haha. I've read through my notes about 10,000 times.

Comment: I'm right there with you. Talked with the TA and hoffman but I'm still stuck. Any help as to how to implement what I previously mentioned would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If all else fails Matt you could just output what it wants and pray. That is the last resort

Comment: Yeah I hear you, I understand exactly what they're saying, but I don't understand HOW do I do this. I don't see the connection between "mapping" binary T/F statements to specific numbers. This problem has been driving me insane. It wouldn't be so bad if it wasn't my first time programming, lol.

Comment: You either take an item, or not, that's true or false. You can construct a number of 16 true-false's, treat them as bits. The number will be between 0 and 65535 inclusive. Here you need the opposite, run a variable from 0 to 65535 and deconstruct it into 16 individual bits. Think.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you are allowed one array. Presumably, that array holds the first set of data.
So your approach needs to not have any additional arrays.

The bit-vector is simply a mental model construct in this case. The idea is this: if you try every possible combination (note, NOT permutation), then you are going to find the closest sum to your target. So lets say you have N numbers. That means you have `2^N` possible combinations.

The bit-vector approach is to number each combination with `0` to `2^N - 1`, and try each one.

Assuming you have less that 32 numbers in the array, you essentially have an outer loop like this:

```
int numberOfCombinations = (1 << numbers.length - 1) - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCombinations; ++i) { ... }
```

for each value of `i`, you need to go over each number in `numbers`, deciding to add or skip based on shifts and bitmasks of `i`.

Comment: While one can do that, that algorithm can be expressed a lot more clearly using recursion, and scales very poorly (n * 2 ^ n array accesses). It is possible that algorithm was asked for, but I wouldn't call this a good motivating example for bitwise operations.

Comment: Totally agree. Hopefully they dig deeper into this topic, to talk about branch elimination etc. I was trying to give just the right amount of help on the homework here...

Answer (score 0):

So the task is to what an algorithm that, given a set `A` of non-negative numbers and a goal value `k`, determines whether there is a subset of `A` such that the sum of its elements is `k`.

I'd approach this using induction over A, keeping track of which numbers <= k are sums of a subset of the set of elements processed so far. That is:

```
boolean[] reachable = new boolean[k+1];
reachable[0] = true;
for (int a : A) {
    // compute the new reachable
    // hint: what's the relationship between subsets of S and S \/ {a} ?
}
return reachable[k];
```

A bitmap is, mathematically speaking, a function mapping a range of numbers onto {0, 1}. A `boolean[]` maps array indices to booleans. So one could call a `boolean[]` a bitmap.

One disadvanatage of using a `boolean[]` is that you must process each array element individually. Instead, one could use that a long holds 64 bits, and use bitshifting and masking operations to process 64 "array" elements at a time. But that sort of microoptimization is error-prone and rather involved, so not commonly done in code that should be reliable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
public boolean equalsTarget( int bitmap, int [] numbers, int target ) {
  int sum = 0; // this is the variable we're storing the running sum of our numbers
  int mask = 1; // this is the bitmask that we're using to query the bitmap
  for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) { // for each number in our array
    if( bitmap & mask > 0 ) { // test if the ith bit is 1
        sum += numbers[ i ]; // and add the ith number to the sum if it is
    } 
    mask <<= 1; // shift the mask bit left by 1
  }
  return sum == target; //if the sum equals the target, this bitmap is a match
}
```

The rest of your code is fairly simple, you just feed every possible value of your bitmap (1..65535) into this method and act on the result.

P.s.: Please make sure that you fully understand the solution and not just copy it, otherwise you're just cheating yourself. :)

P.p.s: Using `int` works in this case, as `int` is 32 bit wide and we only need 16. Be careful with bitwise operations though if you need all the bits, as all primitive integer types (byte, short, int, long) are signed in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple steps in solving this.  First you need to enumerate all the possible bit maps.  As others have pointed out you can do this easily by incrementing an integer from 0 to 2^n - 1.

Once you have that, you can iterate over all the possible bit maps you just need a way to take that bit map and "apply" it to an array to generate the sum of the elements at all indexes represented by the map.  The following method is an example of how to do that:

```
private static int bitmapSum(int[] input, int bitmap) {
    // a variable for holding the running total
    int sum = 0;

    // iterate over each element in our array
    // adding only the values specified by the bitmap
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        int mask = 1 << i;
        if ((bitmap & mask) != 0) {
            // If the index is part of the bitmap, add it to the total;
            sum += input[i];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This function will take an integer array and a bit map (represented as an integer) and return the sum of all the elements in the array whose index are present in the mask.

The key to this function is the ability to determine if a given index is in fact in the bit map.  That is accomplished by first creating a bit mask for the desired index and then applying that mask to the bit map to test if that value is set.

Basically we want to build an integer where only one bit is set and all the others are zero.  We can then bitwise AND that mask with the bit map and test if a particular position is set by comparing the result to 0.

Lets say we have an 8-bit map like the following:

```
map:       1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
           ---------------
indexes:   7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

To test the value for index 4 we would need a bit mask that looks like the following:

```
mask:      0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
           ---------------
indexes:   7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

To build the mask we simply start with 1 and shift it by N:

```
1:            0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
shift by 1:   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
shift by 2:   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
shift by 3:   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
shift by 4:   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Once we have this we can apply the mask to the map and see if the value is set:

```
map:             1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
mask:            0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
                 ---------------
result of AND:   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Since the result is != 0 we can tell that index 4 is included in the map.

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you all enough. I'm new to this Java stuff, so I'm pretty horrible. I hope I'm not wasting any more time if I ask, when you say "enumerate all possible bitmaps" how exactly should I do that? Do I just set up a for loop from (int i=0;i<=65535; i++)? What I'm not understanding is how I get my "int bitmap" value. I'm sorry I suck so bad at this. Your explanation of everything else made a lot of sense.

Comment: @Matthew, yes you just do a simple for loop from 0 to 65535.  Do you understand why that works?  If not, think about how you would enumerate all the 1-bit bit maps.  It's pretty easy, 0, 1.  Now to make it 2-bits you just have to repeat that same pattern twice, once when the new bit is 0 and again when it's 1.  So we get 00, 01, 10, 11.  You can keep going with this up to as many bits as you like, but what you should notice is that if you look at those lists of bits as binary integers we're really just counting from 0 to 2^N - 1. In the 2-bit example the numbers are just 0, 1, 2, 3.